# Azure Virtual Network Subnets Missing/Disappeared

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a resource group with a virtual network in Azure. The virtual network has subnets, but they are not appearing in the list, nor are they returned by the following cloud shell line:

```
az network vnet subnet list --vnet-name [vnet] --resource-group [resource group]
```

You would think that this is because they do not exist.  However, one of these subnets has a load balancer, and two more have running containers in them.  These resources are all still working.  I can still access the containers through the load balancer, and the containers still have the same private IP addresses as before.

Furthermore, I can create create a new subnet with the same address space and Azure does not raise any errors or objections, then delete that subnet, and the load balancer and containers are still running just fine.

I think the problem may have been created when I created a new virtual machine in a fourth subnet of this network that had already been Delegated to ContainerInstance.  You would think that Azure would throw an error and not let me do that, for everything else it complains about, but here we are.

Is there some kind of orphan virtual network that these subnets are in now?  How do I troubleshoot this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment working fine for me and able to get details of all of my subnet under a specific VNET even though for few of my subnet is delegated to particuler service and few of them attached to resources.

[image]

> Furthermore, I can create create a new subnet with the same address
> space and Azure does not raise any errors or objections, then delete
> that subnet, and the load balancer and containers are still running
> just fine

Not sure how this can be happened with you that should not be expected. I would suggest you to troubleshoot this kind of situation please reach out to [Azure Support team.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/)

> Is there some kind of orphan virtual network that these subnets are in
> now? How do I troubleshoot this?

No if there already some of your resources uses that VNEt and their subnet so this can not be terated as Orphan.

Comment: Azure Support Team is only available with a subscription to the support plans.

Comment: So, what's going on here.  These subnets and resources have become orphaned.  How do I get them back where they go?

Comment: We can  not reproduce this kind of scenario. Only support can help here they can troubleshoot from backend and better can tell you whats the problem here .